# Kivy Error: No Screen with Name

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I set up a Screen in a Kivy ScreenManager (myScreen is just a class that inherits Screen)

```
class firstScreen(myScreen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(firstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "first"
        self.add_widget(Button(on_release = switchScreens("second")))
```

I also set up a second screen:

```
class secondScreen(myScreen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(secondScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "second"
```

I then set up my ScreenManager:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(firstScreen())
sm.add_widget(secondScreen())
```

And here is the code for switchScreens:

```
def switchScreens(next):
    sm.current = next
```

When I run sm, I get the following error:

> kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "second".

This seems wrong to me, since I added the secondScreen() to sm, with a name of "second".

How can I get the Button on firstScreen to correctly send the app to secondScreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the names inside here, not the screen classes:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(firstScreen())
sm.add_widget(secondScreen())
```

above should be:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(firstScreen(name="first"))
sm.add_widget(secondScreen(name="second"))
```